# how do I replace :target so my css still works and I dont need to append to my url?

Tags: css

I'm working on a tutorial that currently uses :target which looks out for #clock in the url. I want to remove #clock from the url and just use index.html but I'm unsure how I update the css so my animation still works. Can anyone advise? I tried combining the transition code abd transform code but this didnt work.

CSS

```
#clock img[src*='second'] {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 600000s linear;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 600000s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform 600000s linear;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 600000s linear;
transition: transform 600000s linear;
}

#clock:target img[src*='second'] {
-webkit-transform: rotate(3600000deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(3600000deg);
-o-transform: rotate(3600000deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(3600000deg);
-transform: rotate(3600000deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="experiment">
  <p class="start"><a href="#clock" id="start">Start Clock</a></p>
  <div id="clock">
          <div id="hour"><img src="img/hourHand.png" /></div>
          <div id="minute"><img src="img/minuteHand.png" /></div>
          <div id="second"><img src="img/secondHand.png" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATED

```
#clock #second img {-webkit-animation: loading 1000s infinite;}

@keyframes loading{
  0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(3600000deg);}
}
```

Comment: `:target` requires a hash fragment that corresponds to an ID of some element to work, so you can't use it with the empty hash `#` in the URL.

Comment: @BoltClock The OP doesn't need to use a `:target` now. He just wants to start the animation, which can be done by `@keyframes`.

Comment: @styler Is it working after you have updated? What is the issue now?